# Can we perform CRUD operations in only 1 view with Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view where I list all data from my test table . Now I want to edit in the same view , without using any other views . Suppose there are 10 records in the view . If I click on the Edit button besides anyone of 10 record say 9 . Then I want the 9th record to be in Edit view where as the rest 9 records be in display state . Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in MVC requires you to tie a given view to a single action. In order to support CRUD operations you simply need to write methods in your controller(s) which provide the given functionality. You then link to these methods from your MVC view by providing the appropriate links (i.e. a delete link would link to your delete method, etc.) Needless to say you can call these methods via AJAX just as you could by visiting the link directly. Everything else such as what appears editable, what cannot be edited, how the user will provide their data is handled by the view directly.

Comment: But I dont want to create actionresult method , You are not understanding my scenario .I want functionality just like .net grid view where we are allowed to edit the record on which we click without postback

Comment: You don't need to create a method which returns an ActionResult. You can return whatever you would like. For example if you just want to confirm that you have edited the record correctly you can return a bool. You call the URL of the method with Ajax just as you would any other url. It is up to you on the client side to decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The most common way to achieve this is using ajax. Basically, you would have the element with text (lets say its a `<span>`) and hidden edit fields. When user clicks on "edit", you hide the `<span>` element and shows the editor field for this. On "save" button you will call a controller action (again ajax) and depending on the result hide the editor field, update and show `<span>` elements.